# Can the heaviest edge ever be in an MST?

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

Is it true that the heaviest edge in a directed graph can not be in the MST of that graph?

I don't think it is true because we might end up with a heaviest edge that is *not* part of a cycle.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Let $G$ be a graph with a [bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not true. Consider a graph with 2 vertices and an edge between them. This is the heaviest edge, and it will be in the minimum spanning tree of $G$.

Comment: And this is not degenerate example, a leaf node with the heaviest edge...

Comment: Yeah, consider any pendant vertex.

Comment: Or any edge in a tree.

Comment: More precisely: the heaviest edge is not chosen iff it is on a cycle.

Comment: Every [bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) is in every MST.